# Tkinter session active whilst tabbed out?

Tags: python, tkinter

The title may be a touch vague, but I'd like to make a Tkinter session in Python 3 be active whilst it is tabbed out.

Say I have a function bound to a keypress in my code, and this is built in Tkinter, is there a way for me to keep this keypress function active when I'm on other windows?

Comment: essentially you are asking to capture keyboard input to other windows yes? in which case look at `pyhook`

Comment: I don't think pyhook officially supports Python 3. I have used [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) (also Windows only) for this. You can send artificial keystrokes to any existing window with it.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. Tkinter only processes keyboard events when it has the keyboard focus. If you want to capture all keypresses no matter which app has focus, you'll have to use something else, like [pyhook](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook) if you're on windows. Other platforms will require other platform-specific solutions.